# App loses focus when it uses sendBroadcast with ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED

Tags: java, android, media

I have an app which sends a Broadcast as soon as it starts so it can have a refreshed list of images available. This worked just fine just until today (at least that's when I noticed this).

It still launches, but as soon as it calls the intent, the focus is transferred to the home screen app (default or substituted) and it doesn't come back. I haven't noticed whether my Android phone updated or anything else.

This is the line that causes my trouble:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: That's a system Intent action, I don't think you should be sending it out from your application.

Comment: Why do you think that applies? The documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent) ) doesn't tell me it's restricted at all.

Comment: Intents are not restricted, Actions are. If your app does not actually unmount/mount android partitions, It should not confuse other Apps by sending that Intent. Suppose the launcher(home screen app) listens to this intent, and removes/adds icons of apps that are installed on sd-card. This broadcast will cause launcher to refresh its app list without any real need.

Comment: Ok. I was just using code I found here(http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-trigger-media-scanner-api/). However, how would you suggest I force the system to trigger a media rescan? If I don't trigger it, when I show the images, Android's gallery doesn't show the current state of the media correctly.

Comment: The media scanner is _designed_ to work automatically, if its not working, probably a problem with the Installation. You can just call a [static method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile) to ask `MediaScanner` to scan a file. You could even run it in loop for  all the files in a folder. A well behaving app can always notify `MediaScanner` whenever it creates content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @User117 said,

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

probably shouldn't be used by my app. I can't find documentation that specifically tells a programmer not to use a broadcast of this kind but, like he pointed out the Android OS implementation should usually keep good track of existing items, especially if it's aided by well-behaving apps.

In the end I eliminated the call from my app.